# Reciving userInfo as a message using FCM swift 3

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Is it the way to recognize the content in the message ?

Example :

Firebase -> send your first notification.

`Text : John Canna, 20`

And in the code I would like to get these informations and sign them to variables like `name`, `last name` and `age` ?

EDIT :

I figure out that if i go to advanced options in Firebase console for sending message that i do have place for `key`'s and `value`'s. Whenever i put as a key `NAME`, `LASTNAME`, `AGE` and gave them proper values that in my code i can not catch the message :

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        if let aps = userInfo["aps"] as? NSDictionary {
            if let alert = aps["alert"] as? NSDictionary {
                if let message = alert["message"] as? NSString {
                    let name = message.value(forKey: "NAME")
                    let lastName = message.value(forKey: "LASTNAME")
                    let age = message.value(forKey: "AGE")
                }
            } else if let alert = aps["alert"] as? NSString {

            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance!